# How to move the text in li inside the #nav instead of changing the size of the block of the li

Tags: html, css

In the #nav ul li, i cant seem to fix the position of the text without changing the size of the block. Whenever I try to use padding, the size of the block changes. How can I move the text without changing the size of the block? Here is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

body
{
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #FFC0CB;
}
#container
{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:100%;
    height: 1500px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#header
{
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: red;  
    margin: 0px;

}


#headTable
{
    float:right;
}

#logo
{
    background-color: green;
    margin: 5px 0px 5px 70px;
    float: left;
    width:150px;
    height:100px;
}

#headTable ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
}

#headTable ul li
{
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    color: black;
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 50px;
}

#headTable ul li:hover
{
    background-color: blue;
    color:red;
}

#nav
{
    clear: both;
    width:100%;
    height: 95px;
    background-color: purple;

}

#nav ul
{
    overflow: auto;/*
    background-color: yellow;*/
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

#nav ul li
{

    background-color: black;
    color:white;
    font-size: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: underline;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
    float: left;
    /*text-indent: 0px;
*/}

#page
{
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    height:700px;
    width:700px;
    background-color: #FFC0CB;

}

#page p
{
    padding:100px 0px 0px 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: navy; 

}


#content
{
    height: 1000px;
    width: 1334px;
    position: absolute;
    margin:0px; 
    background-color: #00B2EE;

}
#top
{
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: #7A67EE;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
}

#low
{ 
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    float: right;
    margin:-300px 10px 10px 10px;
    background-color: #7A67EE;
    width:500px;
    height:300px;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="logo"> 
            <img src="plane.jpg" width="150" height="100">
        </div>
        <div id="headTable">
            <ul>
                <li>Google</li>
                <li>Google</li>
                <li>Google</li>
            </ul>   
         </div>
    </div>

        <div id="nav">
            <ul>
                <li>Menu</li>
                <li>Blog</li>
                <li>Ins</li>
                <li>BBC</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
                <li>Wow</li>
                <li>Doge</li>
                <li>Such fun</li>
            </ul>       
        </div>

    <div id="content">   

        <div id="page">
            <p>This is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of Page.
            </p>    
        </div>

        <div id="top">
            <p>THis is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of top.
            </p>
        </div>

        <div id="low">
            <p>This is a paragraph that should
            stay intact inside the id of bottom.
            </p>    
        </div>

    </div>
</div>              

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean by "fix the position of the text" nor "move the text". Can you help clarify what you're trying to do?

Comment: Could you give an example of how it currently looks vs what you are trying to achieve? Would help greatly.

Comment: Padding and border width is calculated out-side of the width and height properties.  This means if you want a block with a total size of 40x40px and a padding space of 10px, your width and height properties have to be 30px.  You can either do the math to solve this issue, or you can use another property which solves this issue.  That is to set box-sizing property to border-box.  This comes with browser incompatibilities however.

Comment: To everyone, try changing the padding in #nav ul li, this will result in increasing the space between the text and the surrounding region. But I want the surrounding region to stay fixed(its length, not width will increase) and only the text(which are menu,blog,inc,) to move. Its like i wish to set coordinates for the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the width for an li element, and wrap the nav text in span tags. Then you can move them left or right and the width of the nav li will not change.

```
 <li><span>Menu</span></li>
 <li><span>Blog</span></li>
 <li><span>Ins</span></li>
 <li><span>BBC</span></li>
 <li><span>Contact</span></li>
 <li><span>Wow</span></li>
 <li><span>Doge</span></li>
 <li><span>Such fun</span></li>

#nav ul li{width:70px;background-color: black;color:white;font-size: 30px;list-style-type: none;text-decoration: underline;margin: 20px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;float: left;}
#nav ul li span{margin-left:70px;}
```

See a working solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/73uav/

Comment: thanks bro.... that helped a lot. Can you explain to me in brief how the span tag works? Is it a block or an inline element?

Comment: No problem. You can find more information on span here: [http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) Go ahead and mark this as answered.

Comment: @mdt0093 - For future reference, the community here generally frowns upon linking people to w3schools.com.  The site has many errors and falsehoods in regards to definitions and descriptions of properties etc.  I think in this case you are fine, but for the future, I would suggest dropping w3schools as a source entirely and operate solely out of the w3c wiki : http://www.w3.org/wiki/Main_Page

Comment: @mdt0093 No prob!  I used to use w3schools all the time and then I found errors in their database, and they refuse to fix stuff too.  Entirely unresponsive.  Bad reliability in that case.